# GraphQL server integration with Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, graphql

GraphQL server integration with Kafka

Initially, I had created architecture/design like

> Request API Gateway-> Kafka Producer -> KAFKA -> Kafka Consumer ->
> GraphQL Server(In JAVA Springboot) -> Database

Now in this design, we have Kafka Consumer interacting with GrapQL Server.
Kafka Consumer is also in Java Springboot.

Is it possible to have Kafka Send Message Directly to GraphQL server bypassing Kafka Consumer?

So is it possible to combine both the Kafka Consumer and graphQL server as one application?

Need your inputs on this. The PROS and CONS
Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Why do you have to go through all those steps if the goal is just to put the data in a database?

Comment: Hi Marstran, good question. But the problem is if we have separate Kafka Consumer and GraphQL Server then in that case we need to manage two difference application/containers in Cloud. We will have two Dev OPS pipiline, monitoring,alerting etc. Hence, if we can combine both application into one, then it will help in less management.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have Kafka Send Message Directly to GraphQL server

No, Kafka does not send/push; consumers always poll.

You cannot bypass a consumer. That is the only way to interact with a Kafka cluster, even if the consumer process were "integrated" into the GraphQL server, which might be possible given that there already is a REST Proxy project that supports similar consumption patterns.

Comment: Thank you so much @OneCricketeer for your response. The requirement is that Kafka Consumer and GraphQL server must be combined into one application. The reason for this requirement is because both KAFKA Consumer and GraphQL server is coded in Springboot. So why do we need to have two separate Layer. Hence, Kafka Consumer will poll Kafka Cluster, receive the message and then the GraphQL server starts processing the request. I tried to search on Google for such implementation but did not find anything.

Comment: Or is there a way if we can implement GraphQL server as PUB/SUB? Currently, i am using springboot to expose GraphQL server as HTTP Endpoint. But is there a way to expose graphQL server as PUB?SUB endpoint.

Comment: Pub is just a regular graphql mutation. Subscriptions already exist in GraphQL, but it is not intended to be used in the same manner as Kafka consumer groups and doesn't scale, from what I've read... You can put a regular consumer in your spring app. You probably shouldn't "expose it" via GraphQL

Comment: I see a few resources around github and YouTube if you search "graphql Kafka" that might point you in the right direction, but I don't have spring experience